# How to make dropdown menu in bootstrap with set navigation and for item in navigation

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

I'm including my navbar and I want to add at the end another dropdown option - 'guestbook' with options for example 'Guestbook' and 'Create post'. I am using {% set navigation = [] -%} to create options and then for every options {% for item in navigation %}{% endfor %} to display them. It looks like that:

```
<body>
{% set navigation = [
    {'url': 'home', 'display_name': 'Home'},
    {'url': 'aboutme', 'display_name': 'About Me'},
    {'url': 'gallery', 'display_name': 'Gallery'},
    {'url': 'contact', 'display_name': 'Contact'},
    {'url': 'guestbook', 'display_name': 'Guestbook'},
    {'url': 'create', 'display_name': 'Create'},
] -%}
{% set active_page = active_page|default('index') -%}
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light sticky-top" style="background-color: #f1f0f0;" id="navbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <a href="{{ url_for('home') }}"><img src="/static/logo.png" alt="logo" style="opacity: 0.9;"></a>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
{% for item in navigation %}
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link {% if item['url'] == active_page %} active {% endif %}"
                       href="{{url_for(item['url']) }}">
                        {{ item['display_name'] }}
                    </a>
                </li>
{% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</body>
```

I know that I can create it like that and add it after {% endfor %} but is there any other option? I would like to use options like in `<a>` inside for loop

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown link
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: twitter-bootstrap in version 4.4.1

Comment: Please _tag_ your Bootstrap version and whatever templating program that is.